# Entity autocomplete form API field with ViewsSelection handler

Tags: 9

I'm trying to get an implementation of the [Entity Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603304) Form API field with a view selection handler working in Drupal 9.

I have seen some examples in [New 'entity_autocomplete' form element added](https://www.drupal.org/node/2418529), but it shows how to use a default selection handler and they only appear to work in Drupal 8. Specifically it was possible to pass the `view_name` and `display_name` via the `#selection_settings`:

```php
$form['user'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'user',
  '#selection_handler' => 'views',
  '#selection_settings' => [
    'view' => [
      'view_name' => 'users_view',
      'display_name' => 'users',
      'arguments' => []
    ], 
    'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS'
  ],
];
```

Starting with Drupal 9.x as per this [Entity reference selection handlers should extend a base class](https://www.drupal.org/node/2870971) change record, I noticed that the `ViewsSelection::initializeView()` method no longer does a lookup from `$config['handler_settings']`, but here isn't any reference to what the alternative is in Drupal 9 going forward and whether the `ViewsSelection` plugin was intended to support `#selection_settings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still possible to pass the options exactly as you have - a lookup from `$config['handler_settings']` isn't needed in `ViewsSelection::initializeView()`.

The `#selection_settings` are merged into the `$configuration` array provided to the plugin when it's initialised in [`EntityAutocomplete::validateEntityAutocomplete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Element%21EntityAutocomplete.php/function/EntityAutocomplete%3A%3AvalidateEntityAutocomplete/9.3.x)

Using your code verbatim I can see the settings you're passing where expected:

[image]

Comment: I see indeed that does pull through the Views details, I might have something else disrupting the behaviour. Will come back and confirm, thanks!

Comment: Confirmed this to work on a fresh Drupal 9.3.0 installation, so something else is wrong in my setup. Thanks

Comment: But this doesn't actually work does it? I have tried this even though no documentation suggesting this form element supports views. Regardless of what i set for view or display; output is the same as for default.

Comment: It worked for me and the OP a year ago, on drupal >=9.3.0, that's the best I can tell you